# Raised SendCodeUnavailableError after reaching max_attempts. How to avoid it?

Tags: telethon

I set `max_attempts=1`, and use `/auth` to authorize telegram.

After sending a wrong code, it will raise `RuntimeError: 1 consecutive sign-in attempts failed. Aborting`. I catch this exception, and ask user to use `/auth` again.

But it raised `telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.SendCodeUnavailableError: Returned when all available options for this type of number were already used (e.g. flash-call, then SMS, then this error might be returned to trigger a second resend) (caused by ResendCodeRequest)`.

I've checked the source code, but I didn't find the reason why this raised. Maybe I missed something.

Is there a way to reset attempt times?

I need help.